# how to check how many bits in a byte array?

Tags: c#, arrays, bit

Im creating a download speed test, and im downloading a 800megabit file to a Byte[] in a memory stream with

```
webClient.DownloadDataAsync(new Uri(link), memStreamArray);
```

How can i check how many bits are in the memStreamArray while downloading?
I need this so i can do a calculation on size / time to get the speed in realtime.

Im planing on performing this calculation in the webClient.DownloadProgressChanged event.

Comment: I know everyone has memory to spare these days, but putting 800mb into RAM doesn't seem like the best idea.

Comment: 100megabyte = 800megabit, 100megabyte in to mem shold be manageable for most machines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a DownloadProgressChanged event handler for this. The second parameter in the `DownloadDataAsync` method is just an object you can retrieve in your callback UserState variable, it's just pass-through - you probably have no use for it in your scenario.

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.DownloadProgressChanged += delegate(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.BytesReceived);
};

webClient.DownloadDataAsync(new Uri(link));
```

Answer (score 2):

1 Byte = 8 bits and you have a byte arrray. Count how many bytes to you have in the array an multiply by 8. Or is it a trick question?

Comment: yeah i know mate, i was after the logic to get the BytesReceived in to a var.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure on the thread safety of this, but you can check the [`Length`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.length.aspx) property of the memory stream. That will give the length in bytes, then just convert to bits.

Comment: @newandfresh My suspicion was that it was not thread safe. Thanks for confirming :)